# Setup Goal in Google Analytic with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking

I want to record Goal in Google Analytic tool via JS so first I add code to the page like:

```
<meta name="description" content="iReserve">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ico/favicon.ico" />
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-YYYYYY');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->


</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; display: none;" class="" id="capture">
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-YYYYYY"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

of course, I create a Goal in Google Analytic like:
[image]

Now I add this code into my ajax function:

```
 success: function(data)
           {

            console.log(data);
          
            if (data.data.Status == 'Success') {


ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Reservation', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Confirm Reservation Form', eventValue: 1});

          .... etc ...
```

What is the problem? Why are Goals not recorded?

Answer (score 2):

Are your events registering within Analytics but the goals are not firing?

Your eventValue is 1, but your goal rules specify a value **greater than** 1 to trigger the goal.

Given you've used a static value of 1 in both your tag and the goal rules, I would say you're probably better to just not use a value at all.

Comment: Remove the rule "Value Greater than: 1". Or change it to "Greater than: 0"

Comment: I change it to Grater than: 0 but nothing happend

Comment: It may take some hours for your conversions to appear in the standard reports. Have you checked the "Real time" conversions report?

Comment: Do you see your Reservation events in the real time reporting? (Not as goals, just the raw event)

Comment: hm, not really ... I see this https://www.screencast.com/t/zpdtFmJHjomf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178919/discussion-between-aleks-per-and-michael-m).

Comment: very, very strange

Comment: When I type ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Reservation', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Confirm Reservation Form', eventValue: 2});

in CHrome console this should trigger Event, right ?

Comment: Try `ga('send', { hitType: 'event', eventCategory: 'Reservation', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Confirm Reservation Form'});`